# Excel Pivot Table Output-how to designate it to appropriate cells on another worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of about 4,500 patients and 4,000 ICD Codes.  I used an Excel Pivot Table to count and sort the number of times they were diagnosed with specific codes.  My objective is to list each patients top three diagnoses(by count) in a spreadsheet.

I am stuck on how to transfer the pivot table results to the spreadsheet.

Here is an example of what my data looks like, columns A and B are what I have, columns D thru G are what I would like to end up with:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Columns A and B aren't in a great format to work with and you could probably create a pivot table that looks like D through G instead, but working with what you've got I propose the following:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($D2,$A:$A,0)+1)
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($D2,$A:$A,0)+2)
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($D2,$A:$A,0)+3)
```

In columns E, F, and G, respectively.

What this does is search the column for the name and the shift down 1, 2, or 3 columns for the most, second most, and third most used Dx. This assumes the counts are sorted in descending order.

Comment: Thank you, Alexis!  That works great.  It sounds like the pivot table could have done the job on its own without the Index-Match.  How would you have gone about doing that?  Thank you again for helping a neophyte cut his teeth on this stuff.

Comment: @user5394861 I think it could, but might be more difficult than I initially thought. Try posting that as a separate question.